# Newrelic python for module installation

Tags: python, python-import, newrelic

I'm newish to python and am having trouble getting newrelic to work via only one import statement.

My Code has the following structure:

```
├── DOCS
│   ├── 
│   ├── 
│   ├── 
│   ├── 
│   └── 
├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
├── helpers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── calls.py
│   ├── construct.py
│   ├── endpoints.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── newrelic.ini
│   ├── new-relic.py
├── newrelic.ini
└── reverb.py
```

The main file that is run is reverb.py

This then imports from my helpers (models = db stuff etc)

These all work fine

My `helpers.__init__.py` states to import all of the helpers
`new-relic.py` includes my newrelic connection details.

So, my question is, to get New relic to monitor the classes / functions in my helpers, how do I import it so that I can do my `@newrelic.agent.background_task()` decorator for the functions?

I've tried importing it into the main reverb file, which does import the others, but I get errors.

I've tried to understand the python documentation examples but couldn't grasp their examples.